# Flattening Observable in Observables

Tags: angular, firebase, observable

I need to combine two Obersvables.

```
products
 ---1
    ---name: 'product 1'
    ---supplierId: '1'
 ---2
    ---name: 'product 2'
    ---supplierId: '2'

suppliers
 ---1
  ---name: 'supplier 1',
  ---contact: 'contact 1',     
 ---2
  ---name: 'supplier 2',
  ---contact: 'contact2'
```

In the end I wanna receive the following:

```
[
   {
     name: 'product 1'
     supplierId: '1',
     supplier: { name: 'supplier 1', contact: 'contact1'}
   },
   {
     name: 'product ´2'
     supplierId: '2',
     supplier: { name: 'supplier 2', contact: 'contact2'}
   },
]
```

At the moment I have the following code:

```
this.af.list('products')
  .map(products => {
    let items = [];
    (<Array<any>>products).forEach(p => {
      if (p.supplierId) {
        let supplier$ = this.af.object(`suppliers/${p.supplierId}`).take(1);

        items.push(Observable.forkJoin(Observable.of(p), supplier$, (p1, supplier) => {
          return {
            name: p1.name,
            supplier: supplier
          };
        }))
      }
    })
    return items;
  })
  .do(res => console.log('After Map', res))
  .flatMap(res => Observable.combineLatest(Observable.of(res)))
  .subscribe(res => console.log('Final Response', res))
```

Doesn't matter what I try, I either receive nothing or an Array of ForkJoinObservables.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to use `flatMap` nor `combineLatest`.

I've made a small [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/BBVfnOfuuvfXWURW8zVe?p=preview) to demonstrate how to do that.

First of all, I didn't wanted to put too much code that has nothing to do with the problem and I've built my example without Angular, and using mocks :

Mock for data coming from the backend :

```
// raw objects that simulate the backend
const products = [
  {
    name: 'product 1',
    supplierId: '1'
  },
  {
    name: 'product 2',
    supplierId: '2'
  }

];

const suppliers = [
  {
    name: 'supplier 1',
    contact: 'contact 1'
  },
  {
    name: 'supplier 2',
    contact: 'contact2'
  }
];
```

Mock to simulate your Angular service (which returns an Observable) :

```
// simulate the angular service with HTTP
// use Observable.of and not Observable.from because we get the product list in one reponse
const getProducts = () => {
  return Observable.of(products).delay(1000);
};

const getSupplierByName = (name) => {
  const supplier = suppliers.find(s => s.name === `supplier ${name}`);

  return Observable.of(supplier).delay(1000);
};
```

And finally, the code to retrieve your data as expected :

```
// now let's try to get your data as you want, which is : 
// get the whole product list
// for each product, get his supplier
// merge the data into one big result
getProducts()
  .switchMap(products => 
    Observable
      .forkJoin(products
        .map(product => getSupplierByName(product.supplierId)
          .map(supplier => (Object.assign({}, product, { supplier })))))
  )
  .do(console.log)
  .subscribe();
```

Here's the result we get in our console :

[image]

Comment: Nice, I was stuck for a few hours on this one, kept getting a stream of results, this aggregates my data nicely.

Comment: Hey, glad it helped :)

Comment: @maxime1992, I feel my issue is quite the same.. Could check if possible for you? I don't understand how I can do a same thing (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012380/angularfirestore-return-collection-with-subquery)

Answer (score 0):

Use scan operator. Keep products, suppliers and results in accumulator and join when you can. You might need also cleanup products and suppliers lists when you were able to create a result object( I did not do it)

Scan:

> Applies an accumulator function over the source Observable, and returns each intermediate result, with an optional seed value.

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-scan

```
  let o1$ = Rx.Observable.of({
      name: 'product 1',
      supplierId: '1'
    },
    {
      name: 'product 2',
      supplierId: '2'
    });

  let o2$ = Rx.Observable.of({
      name: 'supplier 1',
      contact: 'contact 1'
    },
    {
      name: 'supplier 2',
      contact: 'contact 2'
    });

  Rx.Observable.merge(o1$, o2$)
    .scan((acc, el) => {
        // product
        if (el.supplierId) {
          // check in supplier queue
          let supplier =
            acc.suppliers.find(supplier => supplier.name === ('supplier ' + el.supplierId));
          if (supplier) {
            acc.results.push({
              name: el.name,
              supplierId: el.supplierId,
              supplier: {name: supplier.name, contact: supplier.contact}
            });
          }
          else {
            acc.products.push(el);
          }
        }
        // supplier
        else {
          // check in product queue
          let product =
            acc.products.find(product => ('supplier ' + product.supplierId) === el.name);
          if (product) {
            acc.results.push({
              name: product.name,
              supplierId: product.supplierId,
              supplier: {name: el.name, contact: el.contact}
            });
          }
          else {
            acc.suppliers.push(el);
          }
        }
        return acc;
      },
      {suppliers: [], products: [], results: []}
    )
    .subscribe(({results}) => console.log(results));
```

Comment: in your example there's no need to represent `o1$` as an observable returning multiple values over time. If you take a look to Benny's code : `this.af.list('products').map(products => ...)`. He gets the whole list in one call. But after that, he makes **one call per product** to get the suppliers

Comment: sure but observable can emit multiple values over time and the scan will accumulate the values. One call to get products is a limited case when an observable generates only one value.