# AngularFireStore return collection with subquery

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have the following function

```
getParticipations(
    meetingId: string
  ): Observable<Participation[]> {
    return this.meetingCollection
      .doc(meetingId)
      .collection<ParticipationDto>('participations')
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(actions =>
          actions.map(m => {
            const participationDto = m.payload.doc.data() as ParticipationDto;
            const id = m.payload.doc.id;
            return new Participation(id, participationDto.vart, null);
          })
        )
      );
  }
```

In the `participationDto` there is a document reference and I would like to get that document in order to return an object (participation) with a mapping of the referenced document.

Something like

```
  getParticipations(
    meetingId: string
  ): Observable<Participation[]> {
    return this.meetingCollection
      .doc(meetingId)
      .collection<ParticipationDto>('participations')
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(actions =>
          actions.map(m => {
            const participationDto = m.payload.doc.data() as ParticipationDto;
            const id = m.payload.doc.id;
            return this.participantCollection.doc(participationDto.participant.id).get().pipe(
              map(pp => {
                return new Participation(id, participationDto.vart, pp.data() as Participant);
              })
            );
          })
        )
      );
  }
```

But then it returns an `Observable<Observable<Participation>[]>`
I probably need to merge, map or something like that but I don't find the right way to get my Observable enriched with my object mapping and keep my `Observable<Participation[]>`

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you try using flatMap in place of map (inner map).

Comment: @ShubhamChaudhary when I replace map(pp => .. by flatMap(pp => .. then I got an Observable<Observable<{}>[]> ...

Comment: I would like to keep the array but remove the two 'layers' of observables.... TT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using forkJoin on the inner list of Observables and switching the outer map to a switchMap.

```
     getParticipations(
    meetingId: string
  ): Observable<Participation[]> {
    return this.meetingCollection
      .doc(meetingId)
      .collection<ParticipationDto>('participations')
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        switchMap(actions =>
          forkJoin(actions.map(m => {
            const participationDto = m.payload.doc.data() as ParticipationDto;
            const id = m.payload.doc.id;
            return this.participantCollection.doc(participationDto.participant.id).get().pipe(
              map(pp => {
                return new Participation(id, participationDto.vart, pp.data() as Participant);
              })
            ));
          })
        )
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mergeMap` instead of `map`

something like below

```
getParticipations(
    meetingId: string
  ): Observable<Participation[]> {
    return this.meetingCollection
      .doc(meetingId)
      .collection<ParticipationDto>('participations')
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(actions =>
          actions.map(m => {
            const participationDto = m.payload.doc.data() as ParticipationDto;
            const id = m.payload.doc.id;
            return this.participantCollection.doc(participationDto.participant.id).get().pipe(
              map(pp => {
                return new Participation(id, participationDto.vart, pp.data() as Participant);
              })
            );
          })
        )
      );
  }


getParticipations(
    meetingId: string
  ): Observable<Participation[]> {
    return this.meetingCollection
      .doc(meetingId)
      .collection<ParticipationDto>('participations')
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(actions =>
          actions.map(m => {
            const participationDto = m.payload.doc.data() as ParticipationDto;
            const id = m.payload.doc.id;
            return this.participantCollection.doc(participationDto.participant.id).get().pipe(
              mergeMap(pp => {
                return new Participation(id, participationDto.vart, pp.data() as Participant);
              })
            );
          })
        )
      );
  }
```

(since it's complicated and nested and no `stackblitz` provided, I am not able to verify the solution, however if it doesn't work let me know to delete this answer)